# Monaco - Code Completion for CommonJS Modules without LSP

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs, code-completion, monaco-editor

I'm integrating the Monaco editor into [Eclipse Dirigible](https://www.dirigible.io/) Web IDE.

This is how the editor is integrated as of now: [ide-monaco/editor.html](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/blob/master/ide/ui/ide-monaco/src/main/resources/ide-monaco/editor.html#L147-L210)

In Dirigible we are using server-side JavaScript, based on Mozila Rhino, Nashorn, J2V8 or GraalVM (not NodeJS) as a target programming language.

To achieve modularization, we are loading the modules through `require(...moduleName..)` according to the CommonJS specification.

Here is an example of such module (API) that we have:

- [http/v4/response](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/blob/master/api/api-javascript/api-http/src/main/resources/http/v4/response.js)

Here is a sample usage of this API:

- https://www.dirigible.io/api/http_response.html

Now going back to the Monaco topic, I'm trying to achieve code completion for the loaded modules e.g.:

```js
var response = require("http/v4/response");
...
```

I found a sample on how to provide an external library:

```js
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib('var response = {println: /** Prints the text in the response */ function(text) {}}', 'js:response.js');
```

[Dirigible Monaco Code Completion with Extra Lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1AgZ.png)

But once `var response` is declared, it shadows the code completion options:

[Dirigible Monaco Shadowed Code Completion Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF50P.png)

I found that there are several Monaco [CompilerOptions](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.typescript.compileroptions.html) available:

- sourceRoot
- module
- moduleResolution
- baseUrl
- paths
- rootDir
- ...

but I couldn't get the code completion of external modules work.

Is there a way to set some kind of "source provider" to the Monaco editor, so once the `require(...)` statement is found, then it triggers to load of this module and eventually will get the code completion working? We've managed to implement such approach approach for Orion and tern.js: [ide-orion/editorBuild/commonjs-simplified](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/blob/master/ide/ui/ide-orion/src/main/resources/ide-orion/editorBuild/commonjs-simplified.js#L49-L69)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reference implementation based on [Acorn.js](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) can be found here:

1. #### Server Side Integration:

   - Server side module for retrieving the JavaScript modules in the System and to provide code completion per imported module: [dirigible/ide-monaco-extensions](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/tree/master/ide/ui/ide-monaco-extensions/src/main/resources/ide-monaco-extensions)
   - Acorn.js Dirigible module: [acorn/acornjs](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/tree/master/ext/ext-modules/ext-acorn/src/main/resources/acornjs)
   - Suggestions parser:

   ```
   exports.parse = function(moduleName) {
       var content = contentManager.getText(moduleName + ".js");
       var comments = [];
       var nodes = acorn.parse(content, {
           onComment: comments,
           ranges: true
       });

       var functionDeclarations = nodes.body
           .filter(e => e.type === "FunctionDeclaration")
           .map(function(element) {
               let name = element.id.name;
               let expression = element.expression
               let functions = element.body.body
                   .filter(e => e.type === "ExpressionStatement")
                   .map(e => extractExpression(e, comments))
                   .filter(e => e !== null);
               return {
                   name: name,
                   functions: functions
               }
           });

       var result = nodes.body
           .filter(e => e.type === "ExpressionStatement")
           .map(function(element) {
               return extractExpression(element, comments, functionDeclarations);
           }).filter(e => e !== null);

       return result;
   }

   function extractExpression(element, comments, functionDeclarations) {
       let expression = element.expression;
       if (expression && expression.type === "AssignmentExpression" && expression.operator === "=") {
           let left = expression.left;
           let right = expression.right;
           if (right.type === "FunctionExpression") {
               let properties = right.params.map(e => e.name);
               let name = left.property.name + "(" + properties.join(", ") + ")"; 
               let documentation = extractDocumentation(comments, element, name);
               documentation = formatDocumentation(documentation, name, true);
               let returnStatement = right.body.body.filter(e => e.type === "ReturnStatement")[0];
               let returnType = null;
               if (functionDeclarations && returnStatement && returnStatement.argument.type === "NewExpression") {
                   returnType = returnStatement.argument.callee.name;
                   returnType = functionDeclarations.filter(e => e.name === returnType)[0];
               }
               return {
                   name: name,
                   documentation: documentation,
                   returnType: returnType,
                   isFunction: true
               };
           } else if (right.type === "Literal") {
               let name = left.property.name;
               let documentation = extractDocumentation(comments, element, name);
               documentation = formatDocumentation(documentation, name, false);
               return {
                   name: name,
                   documentation: documentation,
                   isProperty: true
               };
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
   ...
   ```

   > The complete file can be found here: [suggestionsParser.js](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/blob/master/ide/ui/ide-monaco-extensions/src/main/resources/ide-monaco-extensions/api/utils/suggestionsParser.js)
2. #### Client Side Integration

   - Retrieve JavaScript modules available in the System: [editor.html#L204-L212](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/blob/master/ide/ui/ide-monaco/src/main/resources/ide-monaco/editor.html#L204-L212)
   - Get suggestion per module: [editor.html#L215-L225](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/blob/ff9c0a63fca483c4add443dda53e948f0df494c8/ide/ui/ide-monaco/src/main/resources/ide-monaco/editor.html#L215-L225)
   - Add extra lib for `require(...)`: [editor.html#L301](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/blob/ff9c0a63fca483c4add443dda53e948f0df494c8/ide/ui/ide-monaco/src/main/resources/ide-monaco/editor.html#L301)
   - Register completion item provider for modules: [editor.html#L302-L329](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/blob/ff9c0a63fca483c4add443dda53e948f0df494c8/ide/ui/ide-monaco/src/main/resources/ide-monaco/editor.html#L302-L329)
   - Register completion item provider for suggestions (functions/properties): [editor.html#L330-L367](https://github.com/eclipse/dirigible/blob/ff9c0a63fca483c4add443dda53e948f0df494c8/ide/ui/ide-monaco/src/main/resources/ide-monaco/editor.html#L330-L367)